# GetOptions Optional 2nd value to an argument

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I would like an option where the first value is mandatory, and the 2nd value is optional.

For example,

```
./foo --arg mandatory optional
```

If I use `=s{2}` the user is forced to enter the second option.

I don't want to allow n-number of values...I want to mandate only allowing two values, with the second value being optional.

Is this a feature supported by `GetOptions`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `Getopt::Long` module, using `=s{1,2}` should do it:

```
use Getopt::Long;

my @arg;
GetOptions(
    "arg=s{1,2}" => \@arg,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Getopt::long is to use `Getopt::Std`

```
use strict;

use Getopt::Std;

my %opt;
getopts('a:b:c:;d', \%opt);
```

So `-d` perhaps might be used for switching debugging on in the code.

The colon : after the option means you need to add a value to the switch

***Anything after the semi-colon ; is optional.***

Usage: `perl myscript.pl -a <value> -b <value> -c <value> [ -d ]`